# How to make all the textarea disabled used as ckeditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have a set of textareas which are used as editors.
    I want to make those textareas readonly in some condition.
    I am able to do it for individual textareas.

```
$("#txtHtmlHead").ckeditorGet().setReadOnly();
```

but when  looping through each textareas is not working

```
$('textarea').each(function() {
        $(this).ckeditorGet().setReadOnly();
});
```

I am getting the below exception

```
CKEditor is not initialized yet, use ckeditor() with a callback.
```

Following is the html

Can anybody help?

Comment: [ckeditorGet is deprecated](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR_Adapters.jQuery-method-ckeditorGet). My advise is to update to latest CKEditor, use `ckeditor()` that [returns promise](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery-section-1) and make it simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put a class for text areas that need to be disabled like

```
<textarea class="nd"></textarea>
```

in js write

```
$('.nd').ckeditorGet().setReadOnly();
```

Comment: Adding class is working but need to loop through each textbox.
  $('textarea.nd').each(function () {
            $(this).ckeditorGet().setReadOnly();
        });

Answer (score 1):

you can simply put/attach disabled="disabled" into textarea tag

```
<textarea disabled="disabled"></textarea>
```

Comment: Good, simple, effective answer !

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".ckeditor").attr("disabled",true);
```

Comment: In the latest versions of jQuery, this should be `prop("disabled", true)`.

Comment: Valid in angular using the directive [disabled]="true"